# Jekyll not finding blog posts

Tags: jekyll

[Source Code](https://github.com/ivrunner/jekyll-testing)

I am new to Jekyll and got it installed with Grunt and SASS. My issues is that while my test site will show my new posts, When I click on the post link I get an error "Cannot GET /blog/*example-post-name*".

Grunt doesn't show any errors when running `Grunt Serve`. However if I run `Jekyll serve` I get the following errors:

```
Build Warning: Layout 'article' requested in app/_posts/2015-01-31-optimized-jekyll-site-with-grunt.markdown does not exist.
Build Warning: Layout 'article' requested in app/_posts/2017-03-20-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
Liquid Exception: Could not locate the included file 'blog.html' in any of ["/Users/rich/jekyll-site/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source. in app/index.html
jekyll 3.4.2 | Error:  Could not locate the included file 'blog.html' in any of ["/Users/rich/jekyll-site/_includes"]. Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source.
```

It appears that it cannot find anything in my: _includes, _layouts, ect... folders.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `_config.yml` should be at the same level of `_includes` etc

Comment: When I move anything out of the app folder and put it in the same directory as the config file, it makes `jekyll serve` work. Although then `grunt serve` is erring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your template files are in the `app/` directory, simply build with `app` as the `source` directory.

Add the following to your `_config.yml`:

```
source: app
```

Then run `jekyll serve` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *blog.html* file in *_includes* folder or use `layout: default` in your posts `2015-01-31-optimized-jekyll-site-with-grunt.markdown` etc.